# Replace text based on a value on a certain position

Tags: batch-file, text, replace

I have a set of text-files, coming in through FTP. Once they are in I want to replace the value of a position based on the value in another position. Could I accomplice this with a Windows Command Script?

For example, the text-file contains the following;

-0000000062,790BCEUR

-0000000000,000

-0000000119,800BCEUR

-0000001352,560BCEUR

Based on that value, if it is higher than 999,999 the value BCEUR should be replaced with C____, if not higher than 999,999 BCEUR should be replaced with SCEUR. If the value is 0, there shouldn't be anything there, which is already the case. 
'Simple' way I think would be to check if the value on position 7 is 0 or not-0 and then replace the BCEUR with the applicable value.

Anyone have any good ideas? I'm not really a programmer, so I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Please note that SO isn't a free coding service; so provide code what you've tried so far and describe where you're stuck...

Comment: While I understand this completely I just don't know where to start. I only have some knowledge of SQL and SQL server. If anyone could give some general idea as where to start I could expand from there myself.

Comment: SO is intended to be used for specific programming questions, so you post is kind of off-topic here... anyway, you could start with `for /F` (type `for /?` in command prompt for help); for string replacement, type `set /?`; for conditions, type `if /?`...

Comment: The first character is `-` so it would be position 8 to check right?  Are there blank lines that need to be preserved in the text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply check the digit in the 7th position, because you could have a value like `0020000119,800`, which is certainly larger than `0000000999,999`

This solution uses [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a purely script based (hybrid JScript/batch) regular expression text processor that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "^(-(?:(0000000)|\d{7})\d{3},\d{3})BCEUR" "$1+($2?'SCEUR':'C____')" /j /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

It looks for a string that matches a template like -##########,###BCEUR. The first captured group represents the entire number. The second captured group has just the first 7 digits if and only if it is only zeros, otherwise it is empty.

The `/J` option treats the replacement string as a JScript expression, which starts with the entire number, followed by either `SCEUR` or `C____`, depending on whether the 2nd captured group is defined or not.

Use `CALL JREPL` if you put the command within a batch script.

Use `/O -` if you want the result to overwrite the original file.

Comment: Thanks for the input dbenham, going to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - blank lines are removed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\folder\file.txt") do (
  set "var=%%a"
  if "!var:~0,15!"=="-0000000000,000" (
      echo -0000000000,000
    ) else (
      if "!var:~0,8!"=="-0000000" (echo !var:~0,15!SCEUR) else (echo !var:~0,15!C____)
  )
)
)>"outputfile.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the input foxidrive, going to see if this works.